# Read out string information recursively with regex

Tags: c#, regex, recursion

I got the following input I have to (1) validate and (2) split into pieces. I want to do this with Regex, as it's more flexible than doing it by hand. Also I need this to learn Regex. Those things are quite complex and hard to learn, but it's time to do it.

Following input:

Section1?Section2?Section3?SectionX:KeyName_UnderScoreTolerant12

This is the optimum input. I want now to validate that there's a format existant which looks like "Sections:Key". That's easy for now. But I want to also save each section as backreference, as well as the one after the ":", the key.

Is this possible? Or should I use IndexOf, Substring and those stuff to extract these kind of information. I guess it's quite a complex regex situation, isn't it? I'm most troubled by the recursion...

Tips on how to do this would probably be enough but a solution would be fine, too.
By the way, there haven't to be more than one section. "?" are optional and so is the recursion in this scenario.

Thanks,
ZapStorm

Comment: *"I want to do this with Regex, as it's more flexible than doing it by hand."* Regexes may be more convenient, but they are not more flexible. Regexes cannot be more flexible than a hand-crafted parser. (I'm not saying you shouldn't use regexes, only correcting this misconception.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to capture the sections and also te content after colon if they exist then you can use this regex:

```
(\w+)\??(?::(\w+))?
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/xB8pJ4/1)**

[image]

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-8]   `Section1`
MATCH 2
1.  [9-17]  `Section2`
MATCH 3
1.  [18-26] `Section3`
MATCH 4
1.  [27-35] `SectionX`
2.  [36-64] `KeyName_UnderScoreTolerant12`
```

Btw, if you are learning regex you can use a site created by **Hwnd** very useful to explain your regex. The page is: http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl

The output for the regex above using this tool is:

```
(                        group and capture to \1:
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times)
)                        end of \1
\??                      '?' (optional)
(?:                      group, but do not capture (optional):
  :                        ':'
  (                        group and capture to \2:
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1
                             or more times)
  )                        end of \2
)?                       end of grouping
```

And another useful site to graphic your regex is **debuggex.com**. You can get this kind of  result:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

```
(Section[A-Z0-9])\?|(Section[A-Z0-9]):(\S+)
```

You can use this.It will put some sort of validation as well.

[See Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pN9aG5/2)

Comment: SectonX is allowed so i had to allow that :( just one charcter or digit

Comment: not a problem :) somehow the question is not very clear